# How to change default page of the project to Wiki

Tags: redmine

I'd like to configure my redmine in order that the default page of project automaticaly redirect to the wiki page of the projet. I found some example from redmine forum:
Add this line to your *config/routes.rb* file
`get 'projects/:project_id', :controller => 'wiki', :action => 'show'`
It changes default pages for all projects, but it is necessary for the couple projects.
Please help me with my problem.
Current Redmine version is 3.3.0 stable.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin https://www.redminecrm.com/projects/cms/pages/1 allow do this thing.
After installation the plugin You will need turn on it for specific project and in settings (project setting you find you tab (CMS)) and set landing page for this project.

**But this plugin does some changes in whole system: change top menu etc.**